# Cannot find action for trigger "on fs" in init.c

Tags: android

Init process setup Android system, which parses `init.rc` and `init.<vendor>.rc`, according to each action trigger.

I can find six action triggers in `init.rc` as `early-init`, `init`, `fs` `post-fs`, `post-fs-data` and `boot`. But there are only four `action_for_each_trigger()` functions in `init.c` as `early-init`, `init`, `boot` and `early-boot`.

So, where does `init.rc` action for `fs` trigger?

Comment: @DavidGrayson Why was the android-platform tag removed? This question is definitely not about Android app development.

Comment: I came across an edit of the android-platform tag wiki and saw it was a brand new tag with the same definition as "android".  If you could edit the android-platform tag wiki and explain the difference between "android" and "android-platform" then we can avoid future confusion.

Comment: Actually now I can see there is a difference so I guess the tag is ok.